# Optimizing slow query with multiple withs

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```sql
with matched_urls as 
(
    select l.Url, min(f.urlfiltertype) as Filter
    from landingpages l
    join landingpageurlfilters lpf on lpf.landingpageid = l.Url
    join urlfilters f on lpf.urlfilterid = f.id
    where f.groupid = 3062
    group by l.Url
), 
all_urls as 
(
    select l.Url, 5 as Filter
    from landingpages l
    where 'iylsuqnzukwv0milinztea' in (select domainid
                                       from domainlandingpages dlp
                                       where l.Url = dlp.landingpageid) 
      and l.Url not in (select Url from matched_urls)
    union 
    select * from matched_urls
) 
select l.*
from landingpages l
join all_urls u on l.Url = u.Url
order by u.Filter asc
offset 0 rows fetch next 30 rows only
```

These are the tables used in the query:

[image]

And this is the DDL for the tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LandingPages]
(
    [Url] [nvarchar](448) NOT NULL,
    [LastUpdated] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,

     CONSTRAINT [PK_LandingPages] 
         PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Url] ASC)
                 WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DomainLandingPages]
(
    [LandingPageId] [nvarchar](448) NOT NULL,
    [DomainId] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_DomainLandingPages] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([DomainId] ASC, [LandingPageId] ASC)
                WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DomainLandingPages] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_DomainLandingPages_Domains_DomainId] 
        FOREIGN KEY([DomainId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Domains] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DomainLandingPages] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_DomainLandingPages_Domains_DomainId]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DomainLandingPages] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_DomainLandingPages_LandingPages_LandingPageId] 
        FOREIGN KEY([LandingPageId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[LandingPages] ([Url])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DomainLandingPages] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_DomainLandingPages_LandingPages_LandingPageId]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UrlFilters]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [GroupId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UrlFilterType] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Filter] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_UrlFilters] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
                WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UrlFilters] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_UrlFilters_Groups_GroupId] 
        FOREIGN KEY([GroupId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Groups] ([Id])
                ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UrlFilters] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_UrlFilters_Groups_GroupId]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LandingPageUrlFilters]
(
    [LandingPageId] [nvarchar](448) NOT NULL,
    [UrlFilterId] [int] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_LandingPageUrlFilters] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([LandingPageId] ASC, [UrlFilterId] ASC)
                WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LandingPageUrlFilters] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_LandingPageUrlFilters_LandingPages_LandingPageId] 
        FOREIGN KEY([LandingPageId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[LandingPages] ([Url])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LandingPageUrlFilters] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_LandingPageUrlFilters_LandingPages_LandingPageId]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LandingPageUrlFilters] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_LandingPageUrlFilters_UrlFilters_UrlFilterId] 
        FOREIGN KEY([UrlFilterId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[UrlFilters] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LandingPageUrlFilters] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_LandingPageUrlFilters_UrlFilters_UrlFilterId]
GO
```

Here is the execution plan:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1tHt5pvP

The query is pulling all urls for a given domain and are then supposed to be ordered by UrlFilterType - however not all landing pages have a match, hence the two with clauses.

As far as I can see from the execution plan it's mainly doing index seeks, so I think I have the right indexes. However, the query takes very long to execute, so I hope there might be a smarter way of doing this.

Any input will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I can't find any differences compared to your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64462093/optimizing-slow-sql-query-with-multiple-withs

Comment: If you see my edits it was closed before I added all the information. I hope that all the new information is enough - if not could you please tell me what more to include?

Comment: I understand. Makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

OK, the big hit is at the bottom of that query plan - where it's reading from LandingPageUrlFilters where the URLfilterID comes from URLfilters.

It's getting completely the wrong estimates (out by 70x) and then sorts your URLs taking 30 seconds or so.

If you run the first CTE on its own, I think it will take a long time. That's what you need to optimise.

```
    select l.Url, min(f.urlfiltertype) as Filter
    from landingpages l
    join landingpageurlfilters lpf on lpf.landingpageid = l.Url
    join urlfilters f on lpf.urlfilterid = f.id
    where f.groupid = 3062
    group by l.Url
```

Suggestions

- <strike>First thing to try is to also add a nonclustered index on LandingPageUrlFilters in the opposite order to your clustered index (e.g., `CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX myindex ON LandingPageUrlFilters ([UrlFilterId] ASC, [LandingPageId] ASC)`. Note this will make a full copy of that table which may be rather large.</strike>  It appears you already have a non-clustered index like this (based on the fact it's referring to IX_LandingPageUrlFilters_UrlFilterId)
- The sort on the string field that is nvarchar(448) - which is actually close to 900 bytes per row - will take a much bigger memory grant. Consider adding ID int values as primary keys - it will require less memory and therefore less likely to spill to disk
- Consider, instead of a CTE, create a temporary table (with appropriate PKs) of the section and LandingPageURLFilters and urlfilters. However, you will still need to do a sort when inserting these - which is likely to take just as long.
- Part of the problem (another 10s or so) is a nested loop join to LandingPages. It was expecting less than 4000 rows (so a nested loop is OK) but had to do 220,000 loops. If necessary, consider a join hint (e.g., INNER HASH JOIN rather than INNER JOIN).  However, it appears that landingpages isn't actually required in that query - just remove the table landingpages from the CTE, and use landingpageurlfilters.landingpageid

e.g.,

```
    select lpf.landingpageid AS [Url], min(f.urlfiltertype) as Filter
    from landingpageurlfilters lpf
    join urlfilters f on lpf.urlfilterid = f.id
    where f.groupid = 3062
    group by lpf.landingpageid
```

I think that gives the same results as the CTE I copied above.

Answer (score 1):

First up, your statistics look wildly out of line. Estimated 3,700 rows, actual 219,000. That suggests, at the very least, a statistics update will possibly change the choices the optimizer is making. Because of those row estimates, the optimizer is choosing a seek and a nested loops operation where, based on the data distribution, you're reading 1/3 of the table, 200k rows of a 600k table. A scan here, probably with a hash join, would be more efficient.

The query itself isn't giving much to filter the [aarhus-cluster-onesearch-staging].[dbo].[LandingPages].[PK_LandingPages] table on. So it's pulling 200k rows in order to filter them down to 30. If you can find a way to additional filtering there, you should see a performance improvement.